# Кухонная плита, плитка для ванной

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести слова "плита"(кухонная, газовая) и "плитка"(для ванной) к этимологически однокоренным?

Answer (score 2):

Это не этимологически  однокоренные слова, это одно слово с разными значениями.

> Плита́. В слове этом таится давно исчезнувшее древнерусское
>   заимствование из греческого языка: «плинфа» — «кирпич». «Плинтос» —
>   называли византийские строители тогдашний плоский по форме кирпич, из
>   которого были сложены здания древнего Киева. Отсюда возникли оба
>   значения нашего «плита»: «печь, накрытая плоской чугунной доской» и
>   «плоско обтесанный камень».

https://lexicography.online/etymology/uspensky/%D0%BF/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0

Происхождение слова плита в этимологическом онлайн-словаре Шанского Н. М.:

> Плита́. Заимств. в др.-рус. эпоху из греч. яз. (ср. др.-рус. плита,
>   плита, плит «кирпич, камень» и греч. plinthos — тж.) откуда также и
>   плинтус (первоначально — «нижний обвод печи»). Плита исходно —
>   «кирпичная печь».

https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BF/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0